# launchOptions are nil after using custom actions on Push Notification

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I'm using push notifications with custom actions on my iOS app.

It all works well when the app is in foreground/background, with my code inside `- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler` being called as expected.

However, if the app is not running, clicking on one of the custom actions will make the app open, but the call to `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` is being done with launchOptions set as nil.

If I click the notification itself, instead of one of the actions, it works as expected as well!

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Did you register your custom actions?

Comment: @MarcusAdams yes, I did. That's why they work fine when the app is in foreground or background.

Comment: Could be an error in documentation for custom actions. Try `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:`.